# How can I get an access token using the Green Button API?

Tags: api, energy

I am trying to figure out how to get an access token. I just need an example of successful communication with the API receiving one (or a few) of the tokens and I believe I can figure out. There are several Apps out there that use the API, so I know that it is possible. Their documentation is so obscure that every developer trying to figure this stuff out seems to be complaining as well. This question is not asking for an opinion. It is asking for a valid example of this communication of any kind.

Here is some information I have found:

- [example partial greenbutton response](http://pastebin.com/QKZV5WBy)
- [github](https://github.com/green-button/green-button.github.io)
- [documentation](http://energyos.github.io/OpenESPI-GreenButton-API-Documentation/API/)
- [authentication process](https://www.pge.com/en/mybusiness/services/sharemydata/vendor/authorization/index.page)
- [apps that use greenbutton](http://en.openei.org/apps/)
- [more info](http://www.greenbuttondata.org/espi/application_information/)
- [sandbox](http://energyos.github.io/OpenESPI-GreenButton-API-Documentation/API/)

Comment: Among the information you have found, there seems to be some explanation on how to get an access token. I guess you tried it and it doesn't work; otherwise you wouldn't ask this question. Can you post the code you actually tried? It might be easier for reader to fix your code than to come up with a solution from scratch.

Comment: Regarding the visibility of your question: You didn't provide any language tag. Maybe you should provide an appropriate one.

Comment: I would translate an acceptable answer into any language from any language. I just want to see a use case where it shows exactly what GET or POST requests I have to send it with what information in order to retrieve the green-button response that posted.

Comment: Well, from what I have seen on SO, questions asking for code samples rarely work well. A common response on those questions is often: "What have you tried so far?"

Comment: Dead end after dead end :( Although through direct contact with Green Button, we are getting information extremely slowly. I am hoping they just redesign the entire thing. It seems like every project that used Green Button failed to make that part of it worth anything. It is just too complicated to use effectively.

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured it out. I wrote this function and it handled all my problems!

```
func isGreenButtonAvailable() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: How is this answering your own question?

Comment: It isn't, but it's in my code until future notice unfortunately.